# NextJS/JSX: How to insert dynamically generated JSX without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, next.js

Consider a string "Foo #bar baz #fuzz".  I want to display a "Caption" component in NextJS where the hashtags are hyperlinks.

My current approach is:

```
import Link from "next/link";

  const handleHashTag = str =>
    str
      .split(" ")
      .map(el => {
        const r = /(.*)(#[^ ]*)/;
        const matched = el.match(r);
        if (matched)
          return `<span>${matched[1]}</span><Link href="${matched[2]}"><a>${matched[2]}</a></Link>`;
        return el;
      })
      .join(" ");

function Caption(catption) {
  const linkedCaption = handleHashtag(caption)
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: }>
}
```

Corrosponding HTML has empty `span` tags in place of `<Link>`.  This approach does relies on dangerouslySetInnerHTML.  Is there a way to implement the functionality of `<Link>` without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

Return a component if there is a match, rather than a string ( basically without the backticks and the dollars ), and do not join the array but render the elements in it using map in the jsx

Answer (score 0):

A solution like [react-hashtag](https://npm.im/react-hashtag) addresses this problem.  Instead of using `react-router` as its source uses, you can use your custom Link component, in this case `next/link`.